# Let $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=cos(\pi cos(3x))$ y $f(0)=1$ Find $ g'(1)$ where $g(x)=f(x-1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I have to solve:

Let $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=cos(\pi cos(3x))$ y $f(0)=1$ Find the value of:

a)$ g'(1)$ where $g(x)=f(x-1)$

b)$ g'(0)$ where $g(x)=f(x^2+\pi)$

c)$ g'(\pi)$ where $g(x)=f(sen(x))$

d) $(f^{-1})'(1)$ and say WHY f must be locally invertible.

e) $(h^{-1})'(1)$ where $h(x)=f(x-1)$

f) $(h^{-1})'(0)$ where $h(x)=ln(f(x))$

I do not how to start, I tried to use the chain rule but I could not get anything.

Any Ideas or hint?

I am not allowed to use Integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $g'(x)=f'(x-1) \implies g'(1)=f'(0)=-1$

b) $g'(x)=2xf'(x^2+\pi) \implies g'(0)=0$

c) $ g'(x)=\cos(x)f'(\sin(x)) \implies g'(\pi)=-f'(0)=1$

d) $ (f^{-1})'(1)= \frac{1}{f'(0)}=-1$

e) $ h(1)=1 \; AND \; h'(x)=f'(x-1) \implies (h^{-1})'(1)= \frac{1}{h'(h^{-1}(1))}=\frac{1}{h'(1)}=\frac{1}{f'(0)}=-1$

f) $ h(0)=0 \; AND \; h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \implies (h^{-1})'(0)= \frac{1}{h'(h^{-1}(0))}=\frac{1}{h'(0)}=\frac{f'(0)}{f(0)}=-1$